# Get Email when user edit the specific column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can you help check why im getting this error?

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined**

```
function onEdit(e) {
var s = e.source.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() == "TEST" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
  var r = e.range;
  if( r.getColumn() == 4 ) { //checks the column for HUB side
    var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
    if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
      nextCell.setValue(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
  }
  
}
}
```

Comment: could you include the definition of the variable ```e``` ? According to the error ```e``` is undefined.

Comment: Are you using OnEdit trigger? Is "e" paramter passed by OnEdit? Full function would make more sense, since in this snippet you don't define "e" and according to error it comes as undefined...

Comment: Also you can not run an onEdit(e) function from script editor.  That is probably why e is undefined.  You need to run from the Spreadsheet context by changing a cell value.

Comment: Hi. This is my whole code sorry i forgot to include the 1st 3 line.